# How to use JQuery InputMask with HTML pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, input-mask

I have HTML input box for phone numbers.

I'm using `InputMask` to format input `860000000` in following `8 600 00 000` when typing.

```
$(window).load(function()
{
   var phones = [{ "mask": "# ### ## ###"}, { "mask": "# ### ## ###"}];
    $('#phone').inputmask({ 
        mask: phones, 
        greedy: false, 
        definitions: { '#': { validator: "[0-9]", cardinality: 1}} });
});
```

I'm also using HTML pattern to check if numbers starts with `86` and there are total 9 digits, but with `InputMask` it stopped working, and can't achieve It in any way:

```
<label for="phone" class="first-col">Mobile No.:</label>
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="8 600 00 000" required pattern="(86)\d{7}" />
```

And CSS to add green borders if valid:

```
input:required:valid {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5cd053;
    border-color: #28921f;
}
```

Have you any ideas?

There is <kbd>[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wL5m26r8/)</kbd>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well the mask you are using is formatting the input value, so if you write a number it will be formatted using this mask which means it will no longer match your pattern.

**Solution:**

So you just need to edit your pattern [**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/oSfN1Z/1) so it matches the new formatted value, so use `(8 6)\d{2} \d{2} \d{3}` as a pattern:

```
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="8 600 00 000" required pattern="(8 6)\d{2} \d{2} \d{3}" />
```

**Demo:**

Here's a working snippet:

```css
input:required:valid {
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5cd053;
 border-color: #28921f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.62/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<script> 
$(window).load(function()
{
   var phones = [{ "mask": "# ### ## ###"}, { "mask": "# ### ## ###"}];
    $('#phone').inputmask({ 
        mask: phones, 
        greedy: false, 
        definitions: { '#': { validator: "[0-9]", cardinality: 1}} });
});
</script>
<label for="phone" class="first-col">Mobile No.:</label>
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="8 600 00 000" required pattern="(8 6)\d{2} \d{2} \d{3}" />
```

And this is an [updated working **Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/95ht6yrf/).

Answer (score 4):

No need for using `RegEx`.

The plugin provides a way to add the mask on the element itself using [`data-inputmask`](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#via-data-inputmask-attribute) attribute. In the value of mask `9` will match any digit, while `8` and `6` will match only those digits. By using this, we can fulfill the condition as below.

In HTML add:

```
<input id="phone" data-inputmask="'mask': '8 699 99 999'" />
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The mask `8 699 99 999` will match numbers starting with `86` followed by any seven digits.

In JavaScript, add:

```
$('#phone').inputmask();
```

That's it!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#phone').inputmask();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.62/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<input id="phone" data-inputmask="'mask': '8 699 99 999'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `keyup` event and a `regex` like the following
*No need for using libs*

```js
document.getElementById("phone").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    // restart the match
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
    // Assess the amount needed
    var v = this.value.match(/(\d)(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,2})?(\d+)?/);
    if(v){
      // Save the desired value depending on its existence
      v =  (v[1]?v[1]+(v[2]?" "+v[2]+(v[3]?" "+v[3]+(v[4]?" "+v[4]:""):""):""):"");
      // and yea!
      this.value = v;
    }
});
```

```html
<input  type="text" id="phone" placeholder="8 600 00 000" required onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 && this.value.length < 12' pattern="\b86" title="description" value="8 6"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but this updates after button click, I need to achieve It when typing directly, without pressing button.

Comment: You can add onkeyup event and do the job there instead of on form submit

Comment: @avrilalejandro It would be better to add an explanation.

Comment: Great, but I think this code has a problem with trying to remove the inputted characters. :)